# Creating a Singleton List

Tags: haskell

I want to create a singleton list from each element in the list, with the type declaration

`single :: [a] -> [[a]]`. For Example `single [a,b,c] = [[a],[b],[c]]`

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it, like using `concat` which does the opposite of what I want.

Comment: A more basic way of writing what @bheklilr is suggesting is: `singletons xs = map (\x -> [x]) xs`

Comment: Or just `singletons = map (:[])`

Answer (score 7):

Just use `fmap return`, since `return x :: [a] == [x]`, and `fmap` for lists is just `map`, but `fmap` is preferred since it's more general.

In fact, you could go as general as possible and use

```
fmap pure :: (Functor f, Applicative g) => f a -> f (g a)
```

Comment: I actually prefer `fmap (: [])` because it isn't always obvious which Monad or Applicative instance is being used with `return` or `pure`. Also, since the question is how to construct a singleton list, `pure` isn't really more general than `return`: they are both specialized to `a -> [a]`.

Comment: Late to the party, but... @ReinHenrichs True, this might be overkill for the question, but "forgetting" which specific type you're working with must be the epitome of coding things general / generic. :-)